# Execution time in c++

Tags: c++, execution-time

Trying to find the execution time of my code using this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    clock_t t1, t2;

    t1 = clock();

    // code goes here

    t2 = clock();

    float diff = ((float)t2 - (float)t1);

    cout <<"Execution Time = "<<diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC <<endl;
    system ("pause");

    return 0;    
}
```

but it returns a different time every time it is executed with the same code. Is the code correct?

I want to check the execution time of my code in different scenarios but shouldn't it display the same time when I execute the same code twice?

Comment: Timing isn't deterministic, and for such short ops, it can vary a lot relatively.

Comment: It will never display the exact same time. BTW, try to use the new `<chrono>` functions to time your program, see an example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now).

Comment: What else is the processors up to?

Comment: There are lots of known and unknown criteria that affects the timing, you should never expect it to be the same twice.

Comment: Your OS is important here. Does it do background tasks? Do you move the mouse while it's working? Does your code access the hard disk (so sometimes your data is in the disk cache, sometimes it is not)?

Comment: By the way can the time difference for two executions be minimized by re-prioritizing the task, to a higher or lower level, for example using a nice or renice commands in Linux or by task manager in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock_t/), clock ticks are units of time of a constant but system-specific length, as those returned by function clock. Having mentioned that we need to consider a couple
of scenarios/facts when using this method to find out the time of execution of a piece of code.

**1)** The time a tick represents depends on the OS. Moreover there are OS-internal
counters for clock ticks. Please see this [SuperUser Question](https://superuser.com/questions/101183/what-is-a-cpu-tick).

**2)** Resources need to be allocated for any process to run on the system. But what if the processor is busy with another more important process or even it might have run out of resources. In this case your process will be put in  a queue and will run with a lower priority. But as the clockticks are stored in an internal counter(as mentioned above), it goes on getting incremented even though some other processes are utilizing processor meanwhile.

**Conclusion**

Your method of finding the execution time based on the clock ticks will not
yield exact results but it will give you only an idea about the execution times.